# displaying label over center of UITableView

Tags: ios, uilabel, tableview, centering

im trying to display a label over the center of a UITableView. Im using a UITableViewController. When setting the frame of my label ive tried

```
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 50, 50);
```

which seems like it would place it the center of the frame.

and then adding it as a subview using

```
[self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

but it ends up way off center (lower right corner of the screen).

I assume its the tableView's scroll view that is screwing my centering up but Im not sure how to get around it? Ive been doing most of this stuff using storyboards so I havent really had to mess around with adding stuff programatically much. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want the label to be pined in the center of the screen as tableview scrolls?

Comment: Why are you trying to display a label over your table? Also are you in landscape mode?

Comment: sometimes the table is empty, I want to provide some info as to why that is

Comment: have you try my answer??@StonePreston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.label.frame =    CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2-25, self.view.frame.size.height / 2-25, 50, 50);
```

Or:
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 50);

And set center after you add label on table view

```
self.label.frame = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: this works for centering horizontally in the frame, but not vertically. Its lower than it should be in the frame

Comment: nevermind. I have a nav bar, so I just had to subtract the vertical height of the nav bar and it works fine. Thanks